# Покрытие тестами. Джанго проект

Tags: python, django

Нужно написать тест для проверки сценария проекта:

1. После регистрации пользователя создается его персональная страница (profile).
2. Авторизованный пользователь может опубликовать пост (new).

Тесты пишу впервые. Только учусь. Понял, что это не простая задача. Буду благодарен если на примере объясните как это делается. А также посоветуете дельный и доступный для понимания новичка материал для изучения этой темы. Спасибо.

Comment: [MDN: Тестирование приложений Django](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing)

Comment: Гарри Персиваль написал замечательную книгу «Python. Разработка на основе тестирования» там есть и тесты и джанго.

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо за материалы.